# Can I use Skype To Go to call other Skype users?

Tags: skype

I already used Skype To Go to call regular phone phone numbers, but never to call another Skype user. I would use this to call other Skype users over the regular phone network when on the road.

Comment: So you want to do the opposite? Call Skype users from your phone? I'm not sure that's possible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [you can](https://support.skype.com/m/en/faq/FA1311/how-do-i-use-my-skype-to-go-numbers#4)

> You can call a friend on Skype for
>   free (however the charge by your
>   mobile phone operator to call your
>   Skype To Go local number may still
>   apply). For a break down of how much a
>   Skype To Go call costs, see How much
>   [does it cost to call a Skype To Go](http://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1306)
>   number

Comment: @Sathya, this is great, thank you, I somehow didn't see that it was possible.

Comment: @avernet - Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they don't allow to call skype user from your skype to go anymore.
Sometime ago you could add skype user as contact in your skype to go, now you can add phone numbers only....
Well, it makes sense for skype, otherwise how they can make money...

Answer (score 0):

One way to use it is with [iSkoot](http://www.iskoot.com/products/skype). It basically allows routing from your mobile -> skype -> (skype out) or (other skype user). There might also be cheaper alternatives to iSkoot.

Answer (score -2):

Yes!
check out [skype.com](http://www.skype.com/allfeatures/skypetoskypecall/)

> Using Skype to call another person who also has Skype is totally free. Yep, absolutely nothing. Zip. Zero. Zilch.

Comment: He's asking about Skype To Go, is that the same deal on cost?